# Flyway detects an incompatible MySQL version even though the documentation says it is compatible

Tags: spring, spring-boot, flyway

I've updated Spring Boot to version 3.0.1 and to also tried to update Flyway to version 9.10.1.

```
...
dependencies {
    // Spring
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jooq")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-config")

    // Jooq
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq:3.17.6")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-meta:3.17.6")
    implementation("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:3.17.6")
    jooqGenerator("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.31")
    jooqGenerator('jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0')

    // Flyway
    implementation('org.flywaydb:flyway-core:9.10.1')
}
...
```

Without the Flyway dependency my application is starting and working as expected.
But with Flyway enabled the application keeps crashing and stating that the db version is not supported:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: MySQL 8.0
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseTypeRegister.getDatabaseTypeForConnection(DatabaseTypeRegister.java:106) ~[flyway-core-8.5.13.jar:na]
```

But the official documentation states that MySQL 8.0 is supported:
https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/mysql-184127601.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can raise an issue on their portal.

Comment: I am using the community version and not the paid version with support.

Comment: I don't think you need paid version to report problem in their documentation. Maybe use their community forum: https://forum.red-gate.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL support was extracted to a separate dependency in [Flyway 8.2.1](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/learnmore/releaseNotes#8.2.1).

It needs to be added as per the [Java Usage instructions](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/mysql#java-usage).

e.g.

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in very old version you can not find any suitable version to easily fix your problem. So if you stuck between `FlywayAutoConfiguration` and your `flyway-core` version that can support your db, and you need to upgrade your Spring boot version, The only way for you, is replacement old `FlywayAutoConfiguration` compatible with your supported db and flyway with new version that exists in current upgraded spring boot.

For me, I excluded (`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {FlywayAutoConfiguration.class})`) flyway class in latest spring boot auto configuration, and I added that compatible version that I've worked with it.

see [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-auto-configuration) post for registering your own Auto configuration.